# Laravel - Is it possible to replace/extend a trait from within Laravel core?

Tags: php, laravel

Is this possible? I am using a multi-tenancy package that conflicts with other Laravel packages such as Scout. Ideally I want to be able to replace/extend the `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` trait within the core.

Obviously the other way to do this is just replace that trait with my own one in every job that runs, but it does then mean in the case of things like Laravel Scout I have to rewrite the scout classes, just to replace this one trait, within my own app which feels wrong.

As an example, Laravel Scout has the `MakeSearchable` job class. In order to replace the trait in this model I have to make my own implementation of the class which is identical to the package apart from changing this one trait:

```php
class MyMakeSearchable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use TenantAware, Queueable, MySerializesModels;

    /** @var Collection */
    public $models;

    public function __construct($models)
    {
        $this->models = $models;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        if (count($this->models) === 0) {
            return;
        }

        $this->models->first()->searchableUsing()->update($this->models);
    }
}
```

To connect up this job class, I then have to override the Scout `Searchable` trait too.

It would be nice if I could just say to Laravel "Whenever you want this SerializesModels trait, use this one instead`

Comment: all method class and trait from repository are secondary, primary is user defined. So you can define your own.

Comment: I realise I can define my own... but in order to make my own `SerializesModels` trait and use it across all the classes where it is used by Laravel packages, I would have to extend all of these packages and rewrite/extend many of the classes, just to add in a new `use SerializesModels`. Seems like a bad thing to do...

Comment: This trait is intrinsic to Laravel, thus it would not be advisable to just replace it architecture-wise. As you been advised, it’s best to specify your own function to override Laravel’ trait.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov thanks for the comment. Aside from whether this is a good idea or not... do you know if it is possible?

Comment: You can fork Laravel and change the functionality, extend it and submit as part of its functionality to have it added in later versions ... Use something like runkit to modify opcode in run-time ... options are there.